# Where does Devise store passwords?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This is just a question out of my own curiosity, I would assume that it stores them in the user's table, but maybe it doesn't perhaps this isn't secure? if it doesn't store it in the users table where does it go, and if you know...why?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise stores passwords and other data inside the table associated with the model you specify during setup. During setup you pass it a model name:

```
# MODEL is a placeholder for the model you want to use with Devise, usually 'User'
rails generate devise MODEL
```

The generator then creates a migration that alters the table associated with that model. So if you passed it `User`, the `users` table will be altered.

[Have a look](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/lib/generators/active_record/templates) at the migration files inside Devise.

Comment: So it stores the password inside a migration ? I thought a migration was just adding something to the model so do you mean that that it does in fact store it in the model? --sorry noob here

Comment: No, it stores it in the database table associated with the model you specify. The migrations add the fields to that model. If you tell Devise to use `User`, it changes the `users` table and adds the additional fields it needs to it.

Comment: I've clarified my answered a little.